# How to upgrade php7.1 to 7.3 on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I have `macOS 10.14.6  Mojave`. It had installed `php 7.1.33` initially.
I would like to upgrade `php 7.3` using `brew install`.
I executed `brew instal php@7.3` and it was succeed.

However the original `php7.1.33` is sticked in `/usr/bin/php`.
I tried remove or rename the php with `sudo mv php php_org`.
But it does not work. `Operation not permitted`.

What is wrong?

Please tell me some advice.

Comment: use brew unlink and link. Read here and follow the links. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909101/how-can-i-easily-switch-between-php-versions-on-mac-osx/41820870

Comment: I thought `brew unlink` works for other version with brew. mine is installed php. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I put next script in `.bash_profile`.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.16/bin:$PATH"
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

in your .bash_profile add:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

open a new terminal window and verify the path setting

```
php -v
```

Also, if you use apache, update /usr/local/etc/http/httpd.conf , update to

```
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

then

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```