# Laravel 5.5 to Laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I want to upgrade the version our the laravel project from 5.5.46 to 6.*
It is possible to upgrade it?
also the php version is still 7.0,.. how it upgrade it to php 7.4?
thanks,. Anyone have experience of this and can hep me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should upgrade step by step if you want everything gonna be ok, first since 5.5 > 5.6, then, upgrade 5.6 > 5.7. Some updates have a high impacts changes. Here is the official guide to upgrade your App:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

Comment: Wow,.. this is a little bit hard,.. Thanks sir Jonnathan,..
how about the php versions?

Comment: you must improve simultaneously, as required

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade the Laravel version need to take care of following things :

Please review the upgrade guide docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade

For Compare the version code
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/compare/5.7...5.8

Compare your laravel version with new desired version for double sure. All thigs are working properly.

You can check and switch the php version which you want for double sure.
[How can I easily switch between PHP versions on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909101/how-can-i-easily-switch-between-php-versions-on-mac-osx)

If you have phpunit test case then run that test case for double sure. if something is breaking then you align and all test case pass.

Cheers you are on new php and new laravel version.