# Brew install php, but "php -v" returning info of MacOS native php

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I was using the built in macos big sur apache and php, but an update deleted all the preferences that i had in apache...as it allways does.

This time i wanted to install the homebrew version of apache and php, and followed all the indications:

```
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
    LoadModule php_module /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp.so

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    </FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/
```

after i configure everything, check the config file with: `sudo apachectl configtest` and returned ok. i test my new php with: `php -v` and it returns the same php that i had before install the hombrew version:

```
WARNING: PHP is not recommended
PHP is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
Future versions of macOS will not include PHP.
PHP 7.3.24-(to be removed in future macOS) (cli) (built: Dec 21 2020 21:33:25) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.24, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

if i run `/usr/local/bin/php -v` directly from the brew php folder:

```
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2021 20:45:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

how can i use the brew php?

Comment: You need to remove the one that is pre installed in mac os and then install using brew

Comment: check you current php installation path : php --ini  with both php versions. I do run internally 3 different php versions for some testing purposes (the one that you are using in apache must be adapted to the required one) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909101/how-can-i-easily-switch-between-php-versions-on-mac-osx

Comment: It is not recommended, and is OMHO an *extremely poor practice* to tamper with OS vendor-supplied software @AdarshMohan That is what `/usr/local` is for - a place to add local variations.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to remove system binaries. Instead, you can add an alias in the `~/.zshrc` file. At the end of the file, add:

```sh
alias php="/usr/local/bin/php"
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution was to put this in `~/.bash-profile`

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

the restart the pc, and it was ready, now when i `php -v`

```
PHP 8.0.3 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2021 20:45:17) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: It is not necessary to restart PC. This is enough:
source ~/.bash-profile