# Error: php@7.3 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula

Tags: php, homebrew

I try to install php@7.3 using brew. But, it return error because it is versioned formula. What is it?

command: `brew install php@7.3`

result: `Error: php@7.3 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!`

Comment: I imagine that PHP 7.3 has been delisted because it is [no longer supported.](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php)

Answer (score 306, accepted):

You can only install supported versions of PHP with brew. However, there is the tap `shivammathur/php` which can be used to install unsupported version of PHP.

1. `brew tap shivammathur/php`
2. `brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.3`
3. `brew link php@7.3`

The first step only needs to be done once. After adding the tap, you can install PHP version 5.6 - 8.2.

Comment: This is correct but i needed to do a few more steps. Found in https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php and THIS->https://github.com/shivammathur/homebrew-php/wiki/Cleanup

Comment: I used brew to install python and it deprecated my php! wth! SO this sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 80):

I applied the same instructions given by @derhansen and worked very well for php@7.4:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew link php@7.4
```

Comment: this is just duplicating info 98% of the content in the accepted answer. this should just be a comment to the original.

Comment: And yet, I was happy to copy and paste this for php 7.4 /grin. I'm now smiling at the idea of making an answer now for php@8.0, knowing that it will become useful to someone on Nov 27, 2023 (not really do it, but smiling at the thought)

Comment: Well, this worked for me.

Answer (score 69):

You can also edit the formula and re-enable it. These steps worked for me in May 2023:

1. `brew edit php@7.4`
2. Look for `disable! date: "2022-11-28", because: :versioned_formula`. Change 2022 to 2024 (or later).
3. `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install --build-from-source php@7.4`

Notes:

- A recent Homebrew change now requires the use of HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1
- Although the bottles still exist online, the binaries are broken due to being linked with an older version of icu4c (v71) than what Homebrew installs. So you must use --build-from-source and compile PHP yourself.

Comment: This didn't work for me, both editing the date and removing that disable line altogether still resulted in the same message.

Comment: Try passing in the path to the edited file directly. E.g.
`brew install /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/php@7.4.rb`

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 35):

**For anyone having this issue 2023 (and beyond)**

The accepted answer is an unnessercery step.

@[Mike's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17869049/mike-richardson) answer is the better one, but is missing one important step.

`HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install php@7.3`

`HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install php@7.4`

`HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install php@8.0`

`HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew install php@8.1`

Brew tells you, when you edit the Formula:

```
Warning: Unless `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API` is set when running
`brew install`, it will ignore your locally edited formula.
Editing /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/php@7.4.rb
Warning: Using code because no editor was set in the environment.
This may change in the future, so we recommend setting EDITOR,
or HOMEBREW_EDITOR to your preferred text editor.
```

This way, you still use the official formula.
This of course, works for any formula.

So, just remove the following two lines from the formula:

```
  brew edit {{ formula }} // ex: brew edit php@7.4

  keg_only :versioned_formula

  disable! date: "2022-11-28", because: :versioned_formula
```

Answer (score 9):

When you are using homebrew to install PHP you need to know the versions that are been supported by homebrew.
If you need to install an unsupported version you can do it by running these commands

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew link php@7.4
```

And then if ypu need to check the current version and then shift between php version you can run

```
php -v
brew unlink php
brew link php@7.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem with Homebrew.  The following steps resolved it, combining ideas from [phpbrew#1249](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/issues/1249#issuecomment-1171272732):

1. Edit the formulae

   ```bash
   brew edit php@7.4
   ```
2. Comment out or remove the date-based validation line, so that you can use the formula at all:

   ```rb
   disable! date: "2022-11-28", because: :versioned_formula
   ```
3. Add the following lines after the block relating to "pkg-config" to make `pkg-config` find the compile headers of openssl v1.1.1 before the ones of v3 (which do not define `RSA_SSLV23_PADDING`):

   ```rb
   ENV["PKG_CONFIG_PATH"] = "#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}/lib/pkgconfig:#{ENV["PKG_CONFIG_PATH"]}"
   system "echo", ENV["PKG_CONFIG_PATH"]
   ```
4. Add OpenSSL flags directly afterwards:

   ```rb
   ENV["OPENSSL_CFLAGS"] = "-I#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_include}"
   ENV["OPENSSL_LIBS"] = "-L#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}/lib -lcrypto -lssl"
   ```
5. In the args array for configure, replace `--with-openssl` with the following:

   ```rb
   --with-openssl=shared,#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}
   ```
6. Save and exit
7. Reinstall PHP 7.4 from source using the locally edited formulae:

   ```bash
   HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1 brew reinstall -s php@7.4
   ```

Comment: `HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_FROM_API=1` is no longer required as `php@7.4` has been deleted from the API now. Using this will just cause dependencies to re-download

Comment: This will install openssl as shared meaning you need to enable the extension in php.ini to use it (and you need a built extension to do that). Instead, add `ENV["EXTRA_LIBS"] = "#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}/lib/libssl.dylib #{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}/lib/libcrypto.dylib"` and replace with `--with-openssl=#{Formula["openssl@1.1"].opt_prefix}` to get PHP to build with OpenSSL

Answer (score 1):

BTW, `brew install php@7.4` gives out same warning, but does install php7, so this could be an option

Comment: I get the same error on php@7.4 now, because it too is now unsupported: https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php. There's this line in the php@7.4.rb brew file: `disable! date: "2022-11-28", because: :versioned_formula`

Comment: I wonder why did they put a timebomb instead of a warning. Unsupported software is not the end of the world

Answer (score 1):

On top of [Anuga's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5363197/anuga) answer, I would like to add a note.

If `disable! date: "2022-11-28", because: :versioned_formula` is not found, then look out for the `depreciated` or `depreciate` keyword while editing the formula. Proceed with the identical steps; it proved effective in my case!

**Edit**:

I encountered an additional challenge when attempting to install PHP, despite consulting various articles. Eventually, I identified that my Internet Service Provider (ISP), JIO, was blocking all requests to `raw.githubusercontent.com`.

This is a noteworthy consideration for individuals in India relying on JIO as their ISP.