# Error upgrading PHP 7.4 on MAC after Brew installation

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I have a Mac Air with Ventura OS.
I just installed Brew and after that I can't upgrade PHP anymore.
I get the following error:
Error: php@7.4 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!
How can I solve it?
New to MacOS and Brew.
Thanks
Fabio

No clue what to do at this point.

Comment: Compare: [Error: php@7.3 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70417377/367456)

Answer (score 32):

The message tells you that PHP 7.4 is outdated. You can either install PHP8

```
brew install php
```

or link a 3rd party repository and install 7.4 from there.

For example:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew link php@7.4
```

Comment: This is the ONLY thing that worked. Thank you!

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura and this worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Before doing this, I'm curious how I'd relink the most up-to-date PHP again, in the event I'd like to go back to the 'normal' brew installation? Would it just be `brew link php`?

Comment: It be can brew link php or `brew link php@<version>`. Run `brew search php` and check which versions are installed on your computer then select the right syntax for `brew link php`

Comment: I'm on macOS Ventura and this worked for me. Thank you very much

Comment: It worked for me too. (MacOS Ventura, M1 MacBook Air)