# How to install PHP 7.4 on Apple M1?

Tags: homebrew, php-7.4

I have a Apple M1 arm64

I tried to install PHP 7.4 via brew

```
brew install php@7.4                                                                                                                             ✔  19:28:52 
Error: php@7.4 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!
```

Then i tried with valet

```
valet use php@7.4                                                                                                                           ✔  4s  19:28:30 
Installing php@7.4...
==> Tapping shivammathur/php
Cloning into '/opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/shivammathur/homebrew-php'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 16343, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (677/677), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (155/155), done.
remote: Total 16343 (delta 553), reused 636 (delta 520), pack-reused 15666
Receiving objects: 100% (16343/16343), 2.29 MiB | 6.15 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (12887/12887), done.
Tapped 20 formulae (73 files, 3.1MB).
[php@7.4] is not installed, installing it now via Brew... 
Error: php@7.4 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula!


In Brew.php line 168:
                                         
  Brew was unable to install [php@7.4].
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: php@7.3 has been disabled because it is a versioned formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417377/error-php7-3-has-been-disabled-because-it-is-a-versioned-formula)

Answer (score 15):

This worked for me:

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
```

Comment: I get an error doing exactly that -> Error: php@7.4: Failed to download resource "freetds"
Download failed: Homebrew-installed `curl` is not installed for: https://www.freetds.org/files/stable/freetds-1.4.10.tar.bz2