# inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Collection::offsetExists($key)

Tags: laravel, arrayaccess

NB: Local server PHP Version 8.1.4, laravel project inside composer.json  file have "php": "^7.2.5", version  & "laravel/framework": "^7.0"

PHP Fatal error:  During inheritance of ArrayAccess: Uncaught ErrorException: Return type of Illuminate\Support\Collection::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice

[error displaying below like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDbSc.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Either lower your PHP version level because Laravel framework version 7 does not support it, or upgrade your Laravel version to 9 or 10 to make it compatible with PHP 8.1

Answer (score 11):

That's a php version issue. Upgrade laravel or downgrade PHP. This article covers how to downgrade the PHP version so it matches the Laravel Version.

https://bytexd.com/fix-laravel-return-type-of-illuminatesupportcollectionoffsetexistskey/

Answer (score 8):

in your composer.json update line

```
"php": "^7.3",
```

to

```
"php": "^7.3|^8.1",
```

and run composer update

Comment: This is exactly the answer

Answer (score 3):

You would need to upgrade your Laravel Framework version to at least version 8 and it's dependencies using composer.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases

Or if you want to postpone it, you would need to add `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` before declaring every function that throws the error. **This is highly not advisable.**

P.S. If you updated your PHP version you would have to change the PHP version in composer to the one used, in your case it should be `"php": "^8.1.4"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, using a mac, turns out my php version was 8.1 which somehow is not compatible with laravel version 7. Tho most of these answers are correct, but they did not fix my issues. I followed these steps (if brew is installed):

1. brew unlink php@8.1
2. brew link php@8.0 or lower

Reference [How can I easily switch between PHP versions on Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458819/11801411)

Answer (score 1):

This Issue Occurred because laravel 7 is not supported with PHP 8.1,
so mean While You need to downgrade your php version to <=8.0.
This worked for me.

Hope this will help you too.

Answer (score -3):

run "composer update" on your project directory and it will work .

Comment: Hello Sunny, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please ensure that you read the question fully and are certain of the answer. In this case, running a composer update - although it may solve the problem - triggers a full-on Laravel upgrade which is far more costly than just switching PHP versions on the local machine. I've down-voted your answer but I think you could edit it to explain what the problem is and what composer update will do.