# installed php 8.1 but when checkin php -v it says 8.0

Tags: php, terminal

I try to upgrade my php to 8.1 but it keeps showing version 8.0.

i run

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.1
```

and I get this warning:

```
Warning: shivammathur/php/php@8.1 8.1.27 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 8.1.27, run: brew reinstall php@8.1
```

when I check version php -v i see this:

```
PHP 8.0.30 (cli) (built: Nov  7 2023 01:40:31) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.30, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.0.30, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Any idea how to make it work?
thanks a lot!

Comment: Homebrew should install php in /usr/local/bin, so first check whether it is there, and also check which version it is. Aside from this, your question should specify what shell you are running, because this is also relevant for your problem.

Comment: @user1934428 also relevant is the chip of the 'puter.   For apple silicon, brew installs in `/opt/homebrew/bin/php`.  Finally, check your path , you may have a hard path to an older version in your .bashrc.

Comment: Just to be clear, you didn’t “upgrade” your PHP, you installed another version, and you can now try switching to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59458819/231316

Comment: @YvesLeBorg : I was not aware, that there are different pathes depending on the chip, but after reading about the apple silicon vs. rosetta problem, I understand why this must be the case. Well, in any case it would make sense to first invoke `php` with the absolute path (whatever it is) and see, whethter the location is right. Of course we have to check the PATH then; this is why I mentioned in my comment that the shell is relevant.